# Remove titlebar in xml

Tags: java, android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Im trying to remove the titlebar at the top of my app.

I know this can be done by adding, `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar`
to the manifest. The thing is that this makes the Holo theme disappear on 3.0+ devices. 
Are there anyway I can remove the titlebar and keep the orginal theme?

-EDIT-
Unforiunally this line `@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar` requires api level above 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify different default themes for different API levels.

In Android you have the directories `values-v11` and `values`. The first one is for all Android 3.0 and above (if no other one with higher version is specified). The second is the default one.

In the `styles.xml` of `values-v11` you define:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"></style>
```

and in the `styles.xml` of `values`:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar"></style>
```

If you put `android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"` in the `<application>` tag of the manifest you should keep the Holo theme on 3.0+ devices.

Comment: Yes! Great answer. Didn't know the values-vXX was used different for api versions. Thanks!