# How to customize the NumberPicker

Tags: android, numberpicker

I found 2 built-in NumberPickers:

[image]
<sub>(source: [techbooster.org](http://techbooster.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/NumberPicker_SS_1.png))</sub>

[image]

By default, it's the first one, but when I add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` in AndroidManifest.xml, it becomes the second one.

How can I put this line (I need it) and still get the first NumberPicker?

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998565/how-to-add-multiple-theme-attributes-to-the-same-activity-on-android-manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are setting the non holo theme so you get the non holo numberpicker.

see this as reference, its basically the same thing you asked

[Remove titlebar in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17467134/remove-titlebar-in-xml)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `@android:style/Theme` is the Android theme for devices on API version 10 (2.3) and lower.

If you want to keep Holo support, you should use `@android:style/Theme.Holo`.

If you need to support devices without Holo as well, you will need to create [asset folders for those devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#SelectATheme) and specify the theme there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"
```

if you don't want to display the ActionBar and still get Holo-styled NumberPicker.

Answer (score 0):

Have a superclass named as BaseActivity which gets extended by all the activities in your app. In it's onCreate call this

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

It'll remove the title bar from all of your activities and you can use whatever theme you want. The only drawaback you'll get is the title bar will appear for a fraction of second when launching your app, but won't be seen again.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you can change also the following properties:

Your numberpicker definition in exampleActivity.xml

```
<NumberPicker
<!-- ... -->
android:background="@drawable/customshape" />
```

The drawable/customshape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="@color/numberpicker_color_range_start"
    android:endColor="@color/numberpicker_color_range_end"
    android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

solidColor ... is the main holo color
and a background with a customshape to get additional coloring: